# incrementing data type in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there a certain data type on phpmyadmin that works like in ms access that if you don't specify a primary key, ms access will prompt to create a primary key named 'ID' which will then be incrementing(1,2,3..) as you are adding more records to the database.

Comment: phpmyadmin is _not_ a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to MySQL, the database, and not phpmyadmin, the web-app used to interface with it. You can use [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) to do this very thing. See the `CREATE` query on the [documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for a simple and succinct example how of to accomplish this.